# Ruby - Blackjack game - Array can't be coerced into Integer

Tags: ruby, blackjack

I am trying to build a 'blackjack' game using Ruby. The user is dealt a random card every time they input 'hit'. If they input 'stick' there are some other conditions but not relevant right now. The game is supposed to return the running total of their deck whilst they input 'hit'.

However, I am getting stuck ‘summing’ the running total of the users deck. Whenever I use .sum it says ***‘Array can’t be coerced into integer’***. I believe this is because you cannot ‘sum’ a nil value. I tried the below methods to try and get around this but no luck;

- .compact
- .inject(:+)
- .reduce(:+)
- .map { |n| n[nil] = 0}

Any pointers would be massively appreciated. Also, apologies. I know the code is not as efficient as it could be - I am still very new to this.

**CODE**

```
def score
  kvpz = {
    "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "four" => 4, 
    "five" => 5, "six" => 6, "seven" => 7, 
    "eight" => 8, "nine" => 9, "ten" => 10, 
    "jack" => 10, "queen" => 10, "king" => 10,
     "ace" => 11
  }  
end

def random_card
  cards = [
    "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
    "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"
  ]
  cards[rand(13)]
end

def move 
  total = []
  while true do
    puts "hit or stick"
    input = gets.chomp

    if input == "hit"
      deck = [""]
      deck.push(random_card)
      total << deck.map { |n| score[n] }
      puts total
    elsif input == "stick" && total <= 21 
      puts "You scored: #{total}"
      abort
    elsif input == "stick" && total > 21 
      puts "You busted with: #{total}" 
      abort
    end
  end
end

def run_game
  score
  random_card
  move
end

run_game
```

Comment: Note: `while true do` can be rewritten `loop do`.

Comment: And `abort` should probably be `break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because here you push an array into `total`, not a number.

```rb
total << deck.map { |n| score[n] }
```

Ending up with `total` containing array of arrays. And `sum` method can not sum arrays. Try putting only numbers into `total` array.

Answer (score 2):

Change `total << deck.map { |n| score[n] }` to `total += deck.map { |n| score[n].to_i }`

`to_i` here prevents `nil` value (`nil.to_i # => 0`)

`+=` just add (not nested) elements to `total` array

`total <= 21` -- here use `total.sum <= 21`

But if you don't need `total` as array you can just initialize it as `0` (not `[]`) and then

```
total += deck.sum { |n| score[n].to_i }
```